# Compilation with ScaffCC compared to Qiskit's Transpiler

Tags: compiling

I am new to ScaffCC and wanted to ask if ScaffCC has the ability to compile a program to a limited connectivity machine? Similar to Qiskit's Transpiler ability?

Comment: I did not understand your question but here is what I can understand from it. 

ScaffCC compiles a program written in the Scaffold programming language and outputs it in the form of a quantum assembly (QASM) representation.
You can find more about ScaffCC in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.01902

Comment: Thanks @sohamb172 for your feedback. I am assuming that ScaffCC compiles and generates your QASM code assuming an all-to-all qubit connectivity? If that's the case, is it possible to compile using ScaffCC for a limitied connectivity machine (for example, a nearest neighbour machine), basically adding all the necessary swap gates for a complete circuit on a specific architecture, similar to when you compile a code in qiskit to a limited connectivity backend.

Comment: I am not sure about the architecture part. But, it seems like a part that is not known yet:)